# maven won't compile source folder

Tags: android, maven

I switched from ant to maven to build android project. But i found it quite hard to config my previous ant project with android-maven plugin. After i config this project just the same as official sample project, everything works find except the source fold under main project haven't been compiled. I have checked the pom.xml for many times, but the same pom.xml under sample project works fine but not in my own project.

I found the src not compiled by checking the classes folder in target folder.

Here is my pom.xml:

> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>       
>           com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects
>           libraryprojects-parent
>          1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>       
>       com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects
>       libraryprojects-mainapp
>       apk
>       Library Projects - Main App
>
> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
>         <artifactId>android</artifactId>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>lib5</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <scope>system</scope>  
>         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/imageloader-core.jar</systemPath> 
>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>lib2</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <scope>system</scope>  
>         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/baidumapapi.jar</systemPath>  
>     </dependency>
>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>lib6</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <scope>system</scope>  
>         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/locSDK_3.3.jar
>         </systemPath>  
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>lib8</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <scope>system</scope>  
>         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/umeng_sdk.jar
>         </systemPath>  
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>androidv4</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <scope>system</scope>  
>         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/android-support-v4.jar
>         </systemPath>  
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>lib9</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <scope>system</scope>  
>         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/weibo.sdk.android.sso.jar
>         </systemPath>  
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>pulltorefresh</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>libraryprojects-lib1</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>libraryprojects-lib2</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <!--<dependency>-->
>         <!--<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>-->
>         <!--<artifactId>libraryprojects-lib3</artifactId>-->
>         <!--<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
>         <!--<type>apklib</type>-->
>     <!--</dependency>-->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>libraryprojects-lib4</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>libraryprojects-lib5</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <!--<dependency>-->
>         <!--<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>-->
>         <!--<artifactId>libraryprojects-lib7</artifactId>-->
>         <!--<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
>         <!--<type>apklib</type>-->
>     <!--</dependency>-->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>libraryprojects-lib8</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>slidingmenu</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>libraryprojects-lib10</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2.samples.libraryprojects</groupId>
>         <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <type>apklib</type>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>
> <build>
>     <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
>     <sourceDirectory>${project.baseDir}</sourceDirectory>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
>             <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <extensions>true</extensions>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

Comment: Take a look at: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html Have you followed these steps?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is caused by the source directory hierarchy isn't suitable for maven.

For normal android project the src hierarchy is `src/com/a/b`, but for maven is `src/main/java/com/a/b'.